# SQL triggers across tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I am having difficulty creating a trigger that updates a count of how many students are registered. Here are how my tables are set up.  This first block of code was provided by my instructor.  Whenever a student registers, or is removed, the register_count table needs to be updated with the appropriate count of how many students are registered.

```
Create table Registered
(
    ssn numeric,
    code char(10),
    year int,
    semester char(10),
foreign key (ssn) references Student(ssn),
foreign key (code) references Course(code),
    primary key (ssn,code,year,semester)
);

create table Register_Count
(
    code char(10),
    year int,
    semester char(10),
    count int default 0,
    primary key (code, year, semester)
);
```

Here is my attempt at the trigger so far.  I keep getting a 'multipart identifier could not be bound error.'

```
 CREATE TRIGGER updateCount ON registered
    AFTER UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT
    AS
    UPDATE register_count SET 
        code = (select code from inserted), 
        year = (select year from inserted),
        semester = (select semester from inserted), 
        count = (select count(*) from registered) 
    WHERE Register_Count.code = inserted.code
GO
```

Comment: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations.  Designing a trigger on the assumption that they will always contain exactly one row is generally a bad plan.  If you are absolutely certain there will never be more than one row then please add a check for the number of rows and use `RaIsError` to explicitly inform those who come along later that they have attempted to execute an unacceptable statement.  (`if ( select Count(*) from inserted ) > 1 RaIsError( 'FooTable_Insert: No more than one row may be processed.', 25, 42 ) with log`)

Comment: Will it be a problem that you only do an `UPDATE`, never an `INSERT`, on `register_count`? If a new `code` appears the trigger will effectively ignore it. And the `count` that you store in `register_count` is the total rows from `registered`, not limited to a specific `code`. And `inserted` isn't a very helpful data source when you execute a `DELETE` statement. That said, try the traditional debugging technique of removing lines until the problem changes.

Comment: Another suggestion is to _quote_ names that happen to match built-in keywords, functions, ... . Hence the column `[count]` is clearly distinguishable from the aggregate `count()`.

Comment: Though this can be handled by trigger, just a thought, maybe you can use view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have a *case sensitive collation* and you need to change the line:

```
WHERE Register_Count.code = inserted.code
```

to:

```
WHERE register_count.code = inserted.code
```

In this case though you are updating register_count and you have in your WHERE clause a reference to 'inserted' which you have not referenced in your UPDATE statement.

I think you want something like this:

```
UPDATE register_count 
from register_count inner join inserted
on Register_Count.code = inserted.code
SET 
code = inserted.code, 
year = inserted.year,
semester = inserted.semester, 
count = (select count(*) from registered)
```

Comment: That did not do it for me.  Wouldn't I need to have the two names the same?

Comment: Maybe have a look at the 'count' column name - it's a reserved name so this could be causing problems - wrap it like this [count]

Comment: I just tried that and it still isn't working.  Am I referencing the inserted table correctly?

Comment: To help you debug, add BEGIN and END around your statement and populate your counts and other values into variables. One potential bug I see is where you select X from inserted without an aggregate. Bear in mind the statements could update multiple rows.

Comment: Updated the answer - I didn't notice you are referencing 'inserted' in your where clause, but it does not exist in your UPDATE statement hence the error.